# Python leetcode: scheduling courses to meet prerequisite requirements

Tags: python, programming-challenge, graph, topological-sorting

This is my solution to [Leetcode #210, Course Schedule II](https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule-ii/).

> There are a total of `numCourses` courses you have to take, labeled from
> `0` to `numCourses - 1`. You are given an array `prerequisites` where
> `prerequisites[i] = [ai, bi]` indicates that you must take course `bi`
> first if you want to take course `ai`.
>
> Return the ordering of courses you should take to finish all courses.
> If there are many valid answers, return any of them. If it is
> impossible to finish all courses, return an empty array.

```py
UNVISITED = 0
VISITING = -1
VISITED = 1

class Solution:
    def findOrder(self, numCourses: int, prerequisites: List[List[int]]) -> List[int]:
        adj_list = {course: [] for course in range(numCourses)}
        
        for course, prereq in prerequisites:
            adj_list[prereq].append(course)
        
        stack = []
        found_loop = False
        vertex_status = [UNVISITED] * numCourses
        
        def topological_sort(course_vertex):
            nonlocal found_loop
            course_visit_status = vertex_status[course_vertex]
            
            if course_visit_status == VISITING:
                found_loop = True
                return
            elif course_visit_status == VISITED:
                return
                        
            vertex_status[course_vertex] = VISITING
            for neighbor in adj_list[course_vertex]:
                topological_sort(neighbor)
            
            stack.append(course_vertex)
            vertex_status[course_vertex] = VISITED
        
        for course_vertex in range(numCourses):
            topological_sort(course_vertex)
            if found_loop:
                return []
        
        return reversed(stack)
```

The function is mostly efficient; I am not worried about the complexity.

However, I feel like the nested function `topological_sort` is a bit of a hack, since it's using the `nonlocal` keyword. The function is really doing two things: manipulating the `stack` and also potentially changing the variable `found_loop`.

From a software engineering perspective, this doesn't seem like a very well factored piece of code. I could raise an exception instead, but that similarly seems to be a function that does two things.

How could I modularize this function better?

Comment: Getting rid of `nonlocal` seems trivial. Let `topological_sort` return a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Clear algorithm and naming**. You've done a good job with the algorithm and
using clear naming. I had no trouble reading and understanding the code.

**Declarative constants are good**. Your idea to use declarative status
constants is sensible. In fact, I would encourage you to create such constants
for `LOOP` vs `NOLOOP` to further enhance code readability. On the same
topic, I increasingly give such variables declarative values as
well. Among other things, it can help when debugging.

**Simple, natural-language names whenever possible**. Within your habit of using
clear names, I would encourage you to favor simpler names whenever they work
fine without loss of meaning. For example, `course` rather than `course_vertex`
and `statuses` rather than `vertex_status` (also: use plural for collections).
Those shorter names are just as clear in context, and brevity in naming helps
with readability by lightening the visual weight of code.
As a separate naming
issue, I don't know whether LeetCode requires you to use `numCourses`: if not,
switch to a consistent standard, using something like `n_courses`.

**Convenience variables in the toolbox**. Within clearly defined contexts, you
can often improve readability by using very short convenience variables.
This is illustrated below when checking for already-visited status.

**Separate method, aided by OO**. Regarding your sensible questions about
`topological_sort()`, the easy step already suggested in a comment is to return
a `bool` rather than messing around with a `nonlocal found_loop`. I would take
things further and pull it out into a separate method. The annoyance with doing
that is the need to pass several arguments to the function: `course`,
`statuses`, `adj_list`, and `stack`. However, *and I rarely say this around
here*, you should use more OO. You already have a class and this is actually a sensible use case for a
few attributes: `adj_list`, `statuses`, and `stack`.

**More direct name for the method**. After those changes, it also seemed more
natural and declarative to rename that function to `add_course()`: its job is
to add each course to the stack, in the proper order. Simple naming is good.

**Return a list**. The `findOrder()` method should return a list rather than a
reversed iterator: `list(reversed(stack))`.

**Organize code in commented paragraphs**. Finally, you can improve code
readability further by organizing the code into commented blocks or paragraphs.
The comments can often be very basic, functioning almost as guideposts or
headings (helps with visual scanning when projects get large). When needed,
such comments can provide guidance about purpose, convey a sense of logical
narrative in the code, or provide some intuition to understand the algorithm.
Examples of all of those are among the suggested edits below.

```
from typing import List

UNVISITED = 'UNVISITED'
VISITING = 'VISITING'
VISITED = 'VISITED'
LOOP = 'LOOP'
NOLOOP = 'NOLOOP'

class Solution:

    def findOrder(self, numCourses: int, prerequisites: List[List[int]]) -> List[int]:
        # Course visited/unvisited statuses.
        course_rng = range(numCourses)
        self.statuses = [UNVISITED for _ in course_rng]

        # Map PREREQ => COURSES.
        self.adj_list = {course: [] for course in course_rng}
        for course, prereq in prerequisites:
            self.adj_list[prereq].append(course)

        # Build course order as a stack.
        self.stack = []
        for course in course_rng:
            if self.add_course(course) is LOOP:
                return []
        return list(reversed(self.stack))

    def add_course(self, course):
        # Return immediately if already seen.
        s = self.statuses[course]
        if s is VISITING:
            return LOOP
        elif s is VISITED:
            return NOLOOP

        # Before adding the current course, we must add
        # those that depend on it.
        self.statuses[course] = VISITING
        for neighbor in self.adj_list[course]:
            self.add_course(neighbor)
        self.statuses[course] = VISITED

        # Success: add current course.
        self.stack.append(course)
        return NOLOOP
```

Comment: `add_course` currently never returns `LOOP`, to fix that `self.statuses[course] is VISITING` should be an assignment instead.

Comment: @Jasmijn Thanks, I introduced that typo in a last-minuted edit. :-)

Comment: This is great, thank you for the suggestions!